# Schema.slack.functions.SendMessage is wrapping text after certain amount of characters

Tags: slack, slack-api

I'm using the Slack `SendMessage` function in a Slack app I'm writing - https://api.slack.com/reference/functions/send_message

I followed the slack app hello world - https://github.com/slack-samples/deno-hello-world/blob/main/functions/greeting_function.ts#L47

```
export default SlackFunction(
  GreetingFunctionDefinition,
  ({ inputs }) => {
    const { recipient, message } = inputs;
    const salutations = ["Hello", "Hi", "Howdy", "Hola", "Salut"];
    const salutation =
      salutations[Math.floor(Math.random() * salutations.length)];
    const greeting =
      `Long message here is getting wrapppppppppppped for no reason when plenty of space`;
    return { outputs: { greeting } };
  },
```

However the text is wrapping even though there are no new line characters, and plenty of space left on screen. Screenshot below shows tons of whitespace to the right, but the text is not going into that area. Any ideas on how to tell Slack to not cut off and wrap?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there are very few direct ways to control when text wraps in Slack messages. There are indirect tricks that sometimes work today but not tomorrow. Ultimately, Slack chooses how to render messages based on a number of conditions that change over time. You may find that you have greater control over formatting by using the Web API's `chat.postMessage` method using the `client` interface the SDK provides instead of deferring to the built-in `SendMessage` function too.

Comment: Thank you! I will try out `chat.postMessage`!